# Opening DevTools causes the page to reload rapidly

Tags: html, css, reload, devtools

Whenever I open the DevTools on my website it rapidly starts reloading the page for some reason.

Comment: At the first, Share your `code` or `screen`

Comment: What operating system? What browser and version?

Comment: AliYaghoby Im not sure *what* code I should be posting in this situation.

Comment: AHaworth Windows 11 with Edge 94